# Are these sentences conditionals or not?

Tags: meaning, conditionals

I've always considered conditionals to have a condition and then a conditional outcome. But then I came up with these sentences:

*If somebody found your phone, then that would explain how they found out about your address.*

*If he, indeed, found your keys, then that would explain how he got in.*

*If he wasn't ready, he shouldn't have married her.*

Are these conditionals (and should be written with "had found/hadn't been ready") or are they not? "If somebody found your phone" is not a condition under which we would know "how they found out" -- it's more of an explanation.

To me, one doesn't come as a consequence of the other and that's why I'm getting confused (for example, the way it happens in a sentence like: *if he hadn't lost his keys, he wouldn't be waiting outside now*). Can someone double check these sentences?

Comment: Anything with if is a conditional.

Comment: @Lambie , 'I don't want to know if he's there or not.'. I know what you mean here but it's just not true, is it?

Comment: @Lambie , so you would you the past perfect in all of them?

Comment: No, why use past perfect? That would change the meaning to the past tense in a conditional clause.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry. I was confused, now I'm even more confused. So are these conditional clauses or not? My tutor told my these were conditionals and, thus, I should use the past perfect; but you are suggesting the opposite while agreeing that they are conditionals. I feel like I should know it but I don't get it. Sorry. How would that change their meaning?

Comment: See my answer. There are three basic forms of the conditional. Two are spoken in the present time and the third is spoken about the past. You probably misunderstood what your tutor is/was saying.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're focusing on a 'conditional' being a strict cause and effect.

All of your examples involve a condition from the past that may have already happened or be the case, but is unknown.

In the first two, I think you are incorrectly assuming that the condition (someone having found a phone/keys) has the results of someone knowing an address or getting in a person's house as their ultimate effect. That isn't what is being said. The condition is that, *if* those items had been found by someone then there exists an explanation of how they knew the person's address or got inside their house. If that possible condition isn't the case, then the condition isn't met and an explanation doesn't exist. It doesn't change the events that already happened - they are not conditional on anything.

Conditionals, particularly the 'past' conditional, can be hypothetical. That is the case in the last example - someone is asserting an opinion that they believe *should* hypothetically have happened *if* a certain condition is true. The condition cannot change the fact the person in question already got married - that can't change, so is not conditional. This is like saying "*if I find out you've been lying, I'll be angry*".

Comment: I think I'm getting it slowly. But I even though I can see how that can applied to the keys example, I'm still not entirely sure about the other one with "if he wasn't ready". I gave this example earlier: (a) - I feel sorry for her because she deserves a better man.
(b) - He wasn't ready to stay committed.
(a) - If he wasn't ready, he shouldn't have married her. // I feel like here it's a totally different scenario. But maybe I need to come back to this tomorrow. I just got stuck and I might need some time. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

This conditional is said at some time in the present and so is the conditional with the present tense:

If somebody found your phone, then that would explain how they found out about your address.

**Present tense**: **a possibility**
If somebody finds your phone, then that explains how they might find your address.

**Past tense: less of a possibility**
If he, indeed, found your keys, then that would explain how he got in.

Present tense:
If he, indeed, finds your keys, then that would explain how he gets in every week.

If he wasn't ready, he shouldn't have married her.

Present tense:
If he isn't ready, he shouldn't marry her.

NOW, there is also **past possibility**; something that might have happened in the past. **This is the one that uses the past perfect**:

If somebody **had found** your phone, then that **would  have explained** how they found out about your address.

If he, indeed, **had** found your keys, then that **would explain** how he got in.

If he **hadn't been** ready, he wouldn't have married her.

[Please note: This explanation does not include mixed conditionals.]

Comment: Thanks, but what about the following conversation:
(a) - I feel sorry for her because she deserves a better man.
(b) - He wasn't ready to stay committed.
(a) - If he wasn't ready, he shouldn't have married her.
(Saying if he hadn't been ready -- would it make sense in this context?)
Or:
(a) - I have no idea how he found a way in.
(b) - What if he found the keys you lost a while back? If he, indeed, found your keys, then that would explain how he got in.

Comment: I just don't see them as conditions because to me they logically aren't (but I'm not smart so that could explain it)

Comment: @August99 I really think I have done for you what I could and now you list a bunch of other stuff?? Anyway, if you read my examples carefully, you will see I basically answered a). There are two possibilities there: wasn't ready and hadn't been ready.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm slow to understand these things. I do appreciate your help, I just get confused about what's in the past tense versus what happened in the past. For example, if he wasn't ready - it could be a conditional about how 'he' feels now and it could also be about something that was true in the past (if he wasn't ready then, why would he be ready now?). That's where my doubts come from. Both can work, but when I read "past tense: less of a possibility" -- Im not sure if it would apply to the conversation example I mentioned in my other example. I'm sorry, I just want to understand it

Comment: Don't confuse the verb after If. The minute there is If + past perfect, everything refers to a past time. How he feels NOW can be **TWO different forms**: If he isn't ready, he won't go.||If he wasn't ready, he wouldn't go. Aren't those two clear?

Comment: Sorry but not entirely: if he wasn't ready (when he made that choice to marry her), he shouldn't've. (It's about what happened in the past - but I use the simple past tense which in a conditional could refer to the present but not the past). If (you are right and it really happened and) he, indeed found the keys... (Again it's about something that happened in the past -- but I'm not using the past perfect tense which would be correct in a typical conditional). I'm not sure if I'm making sense but that is what the original question was about. Sorry for not giving enough context in advance

Comment: What happened **in the past requires the past perfect**. *If he wasn't ready* is the simple past but it does NOT refer to the past. That is where you are getting confused.  "If he wasn't ready, he wouldn't say that*. Spoken in the present. COMPARE: If he's not ready, he won't go. You are not listening to me: **There are three types of conditionals**. THREE. I have given examples of all of them. TWO are spoken in the present time, right now. The OTHER is spoken now **about the past**.

Comment: If he isn't ready, he won't go. versus: If he wasn't ready, he wouldn't go. The **only difference** is the **degree of possibility**.

Comment: yes, sorry I get how the degrees work (I think I get it); it's just that I don't see how these could be conditionals in the first place. I think with yours and Astralbee's help I'm starting to get it. But it's not that easy to change how I think about them.  I guess, I just have to follow the rules you gave me for now and maybe saying these things will become automatic at some point. Again sorry and thanks. I might have sounded rude, but it's because I'm not very bright

Comment: @August99 Anything with an if is a conditional. There are three types I have explained. You need to learn how to use them. Right, it might become automatic. Internalization is the best way to go.